# what is the difference between finitely generated module and finitely generated free module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am still confused about the difference between free module and finitely generated module. For example, $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ is finitely generated module, but why it is not finitely generated free module?  What is difference between finitely generated module and finitely generated free module?I understand free module has a basis(not necessarily finite). In my opinion, $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ can be viewed as a $\Bbb Z$-module with basis $1+2\Bbb Z$, but why $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ is not free module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "finitely generated" isn't really important here. You have to understand what are free modules.

A $R$-module $M$ is free if it has a basis, i.e., there exists $\{x_i\}_I \subset M$ (where $I$ can be chosen the be finite in the finitely generated case) such that the $x_i$'s form a $R$-basis of $M$.

This is a very special property, and every free module is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_I R$, for some $I$.

For your example, you have to be clear about which ring you are working with. $\Bbb{Z}/2$ is a free $\Bbb{Z}/2$-module with basis $\{1+2\Bbb{Z}\}$. It is a finitely generated $\Bbb{Z}$-module. However, it is not a free $\Bbb{Z}$-module. Indeed, the only basis could be $\{1+2\Bbb{Z}\}$. But this is not a basis since $0=2\cdot (1+2\Bbb{Z})$.